# Is it possible to create an angular app, without app-root tag in index.html?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am new to angular and am trying to understand how it works, lets say if I have a component login, and if I directly want angular to render it, what shall I do?

Because if in index.html

instead of app-root tag if I write app-login nothing works, it seems app-root tag is necessary is there any way around it?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ATA</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-login></app-login>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i guess first you have to understand angular architect  and its building block first. in order to achieve your requirement you can use app routing .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g2dqzc) `app-root` tag is selector of `AppComponent`. If you want to change it to `app-login` you have to have selector as `app-login` in selected component. Then you need to set  `[bootsrap]:[selectedcomponent]`

**bootstrap**—the root component that Angular creates and inserts into the index.html host web page.

Comment: Why trying to change the base concept of angular if it's not really a must. 
@Karan: just keep the `app-root` as it is. Create a router with redirect to login component and that's it.

Comment: I was just exploring things :), yes that makes sense to create a route to the login component itself. Thanks! :)